# Create a filtered list using 2 or more tags - MobilePush

Tags: marketing-cloud, filters, mobilepush, contactbuilder, tag

We want to create a filtered list with few rules that contain few tags. I have a contact with a "fishing" tag and a "boating" tag, and another contact with only a "fishing tag". I want to create a filtered list of people who have the "fishing" tag but are missing the "boating" tag. Thus, the list supposed to contain only the second contact (only with "fishing" tag), but somehow it contains both of the contacts. this is my filter: (click the picture for a better quality)

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: so the value field, has multiple values like "fishing, boating"? if so you would need to use contains

Comment: Actually that's what I was thinking, but unfortunately, I get the same result as mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting that result is because in the system, tags are created per device & app and one contact can have multiple tags.

So behind the scenes the filter essentially finds contacts with all of the tags AND returns as long as one of the tags has a value "fishing".

To achieve your goal, here is an alternative:

Create two lists:

list 1) value = fishing OR value = boating (as long as the contact has either tag, include it)

list 2) value = boating AND value != fishing (as long as the contact has boating, include it)
in the send, include list 1 and exclude list 2.

[image]

- 1 - is the list 1
- 2 - is the list 2
- 3 - is the result
- F - fishing
- B - boating

Comment: I've tried that, but when I filter a list with value=fishing AND value=boating, no one enters the list. It seems like when I set the first condition to value=fishing, it assigns "value" to "fishing", and then I cannot use "value" for another condition. I think there's either something I'm missing, or there's another way to so so. help?

Comment: Have you tried created the first list as value=fishing OR value=boating?